# How to obtain the number of iterations a solver takes to converge in PYOMO using IPOPT

Tags: python, optimization, solver, pyomo, ipopt

**EDIT**
I want to compare the number of iterations it takes **IPOPT** to converge in PYOMO when using different starting points (warmstart).

If I call the solve method in PYOMO with argument tee=True, information is printed which includes the number of iterations as in this image:
[image]

But I don't know where is this number stored and how to access it.

Is there a way to retrieve the number of iterations?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that iterations cannot always be compared for different algorithms. E.g. an iteration of an interior point method is very different from a Simplex iteration.

Comment: Yes yes, the algorithm is always interior point. I'm trying to determine whether a warm start affects the number of iterations. And also to get an idea of the quality of the initialization point.